# UIPickerView row image selection highlight colour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uipickerview

I currently have a UIPicker which I load in an image for each row using:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

Unlike the normal behaviour using text in the UIPicker row, when using images I get a background selection colour over the image (blue) and was wondering if there was a way to change this colour or even cancel it (probably setting the colour to clearColor). I've tried using highlightedImage on the imageView i'm returning but this didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to turn off the selection bar by doing...

```
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = NO;
```

Comment: Yes, this does not change the colour of the selection however. I think it removes the part which shows which one is selected in the center.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

check this site which will guide ways to create custom picker...
its possible to make change in color using custom creation